# How long does it take for a Djoser access token until expire?

Tags: django, djoser

So Djoser JWT provided an access token when you login, how long until that token expires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide the value in the settings.  I use the below configuration.
10 minutes is probably better for the access token.

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=360),
}
```

Check out the simplejwt docs here
https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#access-token-lifetime

Comment: what is usually the lifetime of a social media access token?

Comment: Sorry I am not really sure what social media companies use.  I think it depends.  30 minutes is probably fine too if you want a longer access token lifetime